# Loading multiple shapefiles in GeoDjango?

Tags: qgis, geodjango, django

I have 3 three shapefiles and would like to upload all of them and project the result in GeoDjango admin.

a) state.shp (for the shape of a state)
b) boundary.shp (to identify a specific portion in the state.shp)
c) beat.shp (to further sub divide the region obtained from boundary.shp file)

What I want to do is the following:

Uploading `state.shp` gives the following result.

[image]

Uploading `boundary.shp` gives the following result:

[image]
Please note new operations are performed on results obtained by previous operations. `shapefile` can be of different types (i.e poly, lines or points).

And similarly any other `shapefile` file which is uploaded should be projected. After following the [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/) I can project single `shapefile` in GeoDjango admin.

If I create separate models for each `shapefile` I will not get combined result.

How can I display result of multiple shapefile in GeoDjango?

**EDIT:** I want my end result to look something like this (load all `shapefiles` on openstreetmap in GeoDjango)

[image]

But however I can load single shapefile only (one `shapefile` at a time). Something like this

`state.shp`
[image]
`boundary.shp`
[image]

I would like to combine both of my results in a single result as shown in QGIS output.

Comment: What do you mean by "project"? Do you mean change the map projection? Why have you posted three QGIS screenshots and no Django Admin screenshots?

Comment: By project I mean to display it on openstreetmap map and have a look at updated section.

Comment: As Spacedman said, the word "project" has a very specific meaning on this site, I suggest you replace is with "display" :). Similarly "shapefile" refers specifically to the file format, once you've loaded the shapefile into PostGIS it is a "geometry" or a "feature". Semantics aside, you might get an answer if you upload your Django models.

Comment: You probably can't do this in the Django Admin area, one record can be edited at a time. Maybe a custom template can be used to show all imported shapefiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case I created a template where I load both data in the form of geojson using url created in url.py

```
#views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.core.serializers import serialize
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import County

# Create your views here.

class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    template_name='index.html'  #the template name in template folder


#state dataset

def state_datasets(request):
    state=serialize('geojson',State.objects.all()) #converts the shapefile loaded to geojson
    return HttpResponse(state,content_type='application/json')

#beat dataset


def beat_datasets(request):
    beat=serialize('geojson',Beat.objects.all()) #converts the shapefile loaded to geojson
    return HttpResponse(beat,content_type='application/json')


#urls.py

from django.conf.urls import url
from djgeojson.views import GeoJSONLayerView
from .views import HomePageView,beat_datasets,state_dataset




urlpatterns=[
    url(r'^$',HomePageView.as_view(),name='home'),
    url(r'^state_data/$',state_datasets,name='state') #state url
url(r'^beat_data/$',beat_datasets,name='beat') #the url beat
]
```

Make sure you add this line below in your setting at the template:

```
 'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
```

Then create a templates folder with index.html file:

```
#index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

{% load static %}
{% load leaflet_tags %}

<head>

    {% leaflet_js %}
    {% leaflet_css %}
   
    <title>map</title>
  
<style>
    #gis{
        width:76%;
        height:550px;
    }
</style>

   <script src="{% static 'ajax/leaflet.ajax.js' %}"></script>
   

</head>

<body>
          <script>
                function our_layers(map,options){

                    // adding open street map

                    var osm = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}{y}{x}.png');
                    // loading state geojson

                    var state = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("{% url 'state' %}",{

                    });
                    state.addTo(map);

                     var beat = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("{% url 'beat' %}",{

                    });
                    beat.addTo(map);


                }
        </script>

   {% leaflet_map "gis" callback="window.our_layers" %}

</body>
</html>


#make sure you have leaflet ajax plugin ,django-leaflet (pip install django-leaflet)
```